# How can we generate a grammar for $\{a^n b^n c^n d^n; n > 0\}$ if it is NOT context free?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma, context-sensitive

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Languages_that_are_not_context-free) page on Wiki states that $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n \ | \ n > 0\}$ can not be generated by a CFG. This does not make sense to me as $\{$**S** $\to$ **ABCD**, **A** $\to$ a**A** | a, **B** $\to$ b**B** | b, **C** $\to$ c**C** | c, **D** $\to$ **D**d | d$\}$ seems to be the desired CFG. By the Pumping lemma for CFG, I understand that it is not context-free but that seems very much contradictory.

Can someone clarify this? I got this doubt while I wondering if [CFGs can generate all languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131550/can-cfgs-generate-all-languages-are-they-pdas-finite-or-infinite-state-automa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar generates the language $\{a^ib^jc^kd^\ell \mid i,j,k,l \geq 1\}$, which is larger than $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n \mid n \geq 1\}$. For example, your grammar generates $abcdd$, which is not of the form $a^nb^nc^nd^n$.

That said, you can generate $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n \mid n \geq 1\}$ using a *context-sensitive* grammar. Moreover, unrestricted grammar can generate all recursively enumerable languages.